# Creating Video from generated bitmap images c#

Tags: c#, wpf, video, bitmap

I am trying to play a stream of bitmap images using openCVSharp to generate the Bitmaps from YUV. But I am unable to display it as a video.

I found some links regarding using it as an AVI wrapper [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7388/A-Simple-C-Wrapper-for-the-AviFile-Library/) and some more to save on the hard disk like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607712/create-video-from-streamed-images-c-sharp/) and FFMPEG might work great on LINUX, but it is not so good in Windows.

I even tried with  by using the following code. But it just displays the last frame in the sequence, and I do not have a URI for using MediaElement as the bitmaps are generated by my program.

```
image.source = ToBitmapSource(bitmapImage);
```

where

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap){
    IntPtr ip = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
    BitmapSource bs = null;

    bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
    IntPtr.Zero, System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    return bs;
}
```

I am trying to play the video (similar to streaming) without saving it on the computer. Is direct show a must for this? I desperately need your help, my deadline is fast approaching!

Comment: Why, can't you simply display them on the screen using XNA or SlimDX?

Comment: I have never worked with any of them, do you have any links regarding the same?

Comment: I was able to find that SlimDX and XNA are high end graphics tools used for gaming, I do not need such high processing, just want to be able to display bitmaps as a video that is all

Comment: What is the rate at which you generate these frames?

Comment: Well then - if your UI can render it already, then what do you want to do (why convert it to a video)? It is already being displayed, correct?

Comment: using the System.Windows.Controls.Image, I was able to just display a single frame - namely the last frame, but was never able to show it up as a video, tried providing delay between this, but in vain.

Comment: Could this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806083/wpf-render-performance-with-bitmapsource) be the solution to your problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) (equivalent to a Timer in Winform):

```
DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
dt.Interval = 25;  //25 ms --> 50 frames per second
dt.Tick += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e){

             //get the image and display it

          }

dt.Start(); //to start record
```

Comment: I have not worked with delegate much, So, here is the error that I got for

dt.Tick = delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) --- Tick can only be applied on left hand side of += or -=. I didn't get what it means

Comment: well, I modified this a little based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9977393/how-do-i-pass-an-object-into-a-timer-event/) and used it .. but it makes no difference, still no video 
            dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 40);  //25 ms --> 50 frames per second
            dt.Tick += (sender, e) => UpdateFrame(sender, e, BitImage);
            
        private void UpdateFrame(object sender, EventArgs e, Bitmap BitImage)
            {

               Image.Source = ConvertYUV.ToBitmapSource(BitImage);         
            }